# How to get jQuery and Python to send data back and forth in a GAE app

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, google-app-engine

I'm a web development novice writing a Python web app using Google App Engine and for the life of me I can't figure out how to successfully pass data back and forth between my jQuery and my Python.  The jQuery ajax function seems to be successfully sending the data to Python as I do get my "It worked!" alert on testing.  But I can't figure out how to obtain Python's response for use in updating a selectbox--I'm not sure if the problem is in my Python, my jQuery, or both.

I don't know if I'm "receiving" the data correctly in Python, (is Python understanding what I'm sending it?) if Python is responding at all, and if it is responding, if jQuery can understand what I'm sending it.  It seems that perhaps I should be sending it back and forth in JSON form?  If so, can this be accomplished without using another tool like Flash or Jinja?  I'm having troubling understanding what these things are, perhaps I need to step back and learn about them more generally before trying to accomplish this task?

(I apologize if this question seems redundant; I've read [Simple Python and Ajax Example How to Send Response with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843068/simple-python-and-ajax-example-how-to-send-response-with-python?rq=1), [How to use AJAX with Google App Engine (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052013/how-to-use-ajax-with-google-app-engine-python), and [Simple Python and Ajax Example How to Send Response with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843068/simple-python-and-ajax-example-how-to-send-response-with-python?rq=1), but I can't make much sense of the responses.)

Here's the jQuery:

```
$presentTeamLoc = $('whatsActiveInTheCurrentDaysBox');
$.ajax({
    url: "main.py",
    data: $presentTeamLoc,
    type: "POST",
    //Okay now I've talked to the server, now I listen back:
    success: function( xml ) {
        alert( "It worked!" );
        $(".day").children("#firstbox").last().append("<option value=5>"REPONSE FROM PYTHON"</option>").hide().fadeIn("slow");
        },
});
```

here's the relevant portion of the Python:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.write(form)
def post(self):
    presentTeamLoc = self.request.get('$presentTeamLoc')
    #"do a bunch of stuff with the data from jQuery and generate a response"
    self.response.write("RESPONSE")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

and finally here is my app.yaml:

```
application: micro-vine-87005
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers: 
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /javascript
  static_dir: javascript

- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

All of the project files are in the main directory, except for my jQuery and CSS files, which are in the javascript and stylesheets directories, respectively. My main.py file reads in the html for the index page from a file, which in turn reads in the jQuery from its file.

Comment: I have a problem. Why your ajax url is "main.py"?

Comment: @TonyYang main.py is the name of the Python file that contains the code above.  Does it seem like my url should be different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you address a URL properly mapped to a handler (via `app.yaml` and the `WSGI` app in your Python code), things work just fine.  E.g, with `app.yaml` being:

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

and `main.py`:

```
import webapp2

form = '''
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>something</p>
<script>
$presentTeamLoc = 'whatever';
$.ajax({
    url: "/",
    data: $presentTeamLoc,
    type: "POST",
    success: function( xml ) {
        alert( "It worked!" );
        alert( xml );
        },
});
</script>
'''

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write(form)
    def post(self):
        self.response.write("RESPONSE")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
], debug=True)
```

the page shows two alert boxes -- the first one saying "it worked", the second one saying "RESPONSE", exactly as expected.

I imagine you're **not** mapping the URL you're addressing, which you peculiarly chose to name `main.py`, and that may be the only thing that's causing you problems -- but then I would not expect the `success` function to execute (and you don't have an `error` function).  And you're apparently not using the `xml` argument to your `success` function at all, so what makes you think it wasn't set properly...?

Comment: thanks for your help.  Your example code works exactly for me as it does for you.  I changed my url field in my ajax call from "main.py" to "/" but I get a 404 not found when I click the button that activates the ajax.  I'm wondering if it's because of my file organization scheme?  My main.py reads in my html from a separate file, which reads in my javascript from another file.  I've edited my question to demonstrate.

Comment: @EequalsMChammer, please further edit the Q to show exactly how you make the `app` global object -- that's most likely where your bug comes from.

Comment: I just did added it, but I think it's the same as in your example.  Do I perhaps have to declare in app.yaml that my jQuery file is a script, rather than a static file?

Comment: @EequalsMChammer, definitely no -- "script:" in the app.yaml names a Python WSGI app.  However if you need to **both** serve a Javascript file from a URL, **and** also read it in your code (an exceedingly rare requirement!), you *will* need the `application_readable` sub-directive for that `static_dir` or `static_file` directive.  Though missing it would cause a 500, not a 404 -- the 404 is just inexplicable from the data you've given.

Comment: Since my very similar but simplified example works for you, and your original doesn't, try simplifying your original bit by bit until it becomes my example -- clearly at some point during the simplification process it will start working, and then you will have found your bug!-)

Comment: Yeah I was thinking it was about time to try that.  Thanks for all your help.  I'll let you know what it is if it seems of interest.

Comment: I think @AlexMartelli 's answer is right. He clearly guides the app how to build basic stack with front-end and back-end architectures.